# Adding quotes automatically on input

Tags: python-2.x

So if I want an user to input his Path he has to add quotes manually.
So it would look like that:

```
Path = input('Enter Path:\n')
```

And how can I add quotes now so the user can write his path in between them?
Like that: " " <---- and in between the quotes the user can enter his path.

Comment: Arguably, this is a prime example of an XY problem -- asking how to do X (pre-enter quotes for the user), when what you *really* want is Y (to collect input as a string without the user needing to enter Python syntax to force its interpretation as such).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Python 2 (as this question shouldn't come up in Python 3) --

Use `raw_input()` instead, and literal quotes aren't needed.

Comment: Your assumption is reasonable, so I edited the tags.